# sort an array by a boolean property in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I am using `angular 10` and I was wondering how can I sort this array

```
var dic = [
  { state: false, id: 1 },
  { state: true, id: 2} ,
  { state: false, id: 3 },
  { state: true, id: 4 },
  { state: false, id: 5 }
]
```

I want to sort by the value of the boolean `state`, so the result goes this way:

```
[
  { state: true, id: 2 },
  { state: true, id: 4 },
  { state: false, id: 1 },
  { state: false, id: 3 },
  { state: false, id: 5 }
]
```

The `true` value goes first in the array.

What property or something from typescript I have to use to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by converting the `boolean` values of `state`:

```
Number(true) //1
Number(false) //0
```

```js
const dic = [
  { state: false, id: 1 },
  { state: true, id: 2 },
  { state: false, id: 3 },
  { state: true, id: 4 },
  { state: false, id: 5 }
];

dic.sort(({ state: stateA = false }, { state: stateB = false }) =>
  Number(stateB) - Number(stateA)
);

console.log(dic);
```

Comment: Yes it works! can you explain in a more detailed way how that works?

Comment: You don't need to use `Number` to convert the boolean value. Just simplify `dic.sort((a, b) => b.state - a.state);`

Comment: Regarding Number, I guess, Typescript wants explicit casting

Answer (score 1):

You can complete it by doing simplify like this.

```
dic.sort((a, b) => b.state - a.state);
```

---

**Explain:**

We all know that:

```
false // 0
true // 1
```

So

```
false - true // -1
true - false // 1
true - true // 0
false - false // 0
```

---

**Demo**

```js
const dic = [
  { state: false, id: 1 },
  { state: true, id: 2 },
  { state: false, id: 3 },
  { state: true, id: 4 },
  { state: false, id: 5 }
];

dic.sort((a, b) => b.state - a.state);

console.log(dic);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the state by casting the boolean to an integer value of `1` or `0` by appending a double-bang (`!!`) or double-tilde (`~~`). If the result is `0`, move onto the `id` values.

```js
const dic = [
  { state: false  , id: 1 },
  { state: true   , id: 2 },
  { state: false  , id: 3 },
  { state: true   , id: 4 },
  { state: false  , id: 5 }
];

dic.sort(({ state: stateA, id: idA }, { state: stateB, id: idB }) =>
  (!!stateB - !!stateA) || (idA - idB));

console.log(dic);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Alternatively:

```js
(~~stateB - ~~stateA) || (idA - idB)
```